# Can circular buffer be re-written with ByteBuffer

Tags: java, byte, bytebuffer

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
int index = 0;

public void recordByte(Byte b) {
   index = (index + 1) % 100;
   buffer[index] = b; 
}

public void printLastBytes() {
   for(int i = index; i < index + 100; i++) {
       System.out.print(buffer[i % 100]);
   }
}
```

Can this piece of code, which is a circular buffer, be **re-written** using `ByteBuffer`:

```
private static final int SIZE = 100;
private final byte[] result = new byte[SIZE];

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(SIZE);


@Override
public void record(byte b) {
    buffer.put(b);

}

@Override
public String print() {

}
```

Comment: code block to be re-written using `ByteBuffer`. question updated

Comment: Why are you rewinding the buffer on each call to `record()`? Shouldn't you rewind it once the number of records equals `SIZE`?

Comment: agreed. so looking to achieve string representation in correct order when print is called at any point in time, return the last 100 bytes

Comment: Have you considered that strings can be represented in different formats (ASCII, UTF-8, etc.)? If all you're worried about is ASCII then it shouldn't be too complicated, otherwise you're looking at a much harder task. Consider the following scenario - the 100th byte you record is the first half of a surrogate pair, meaning the second half would be recorded as the 1st byte. Now you have a garbage value in the first and last index. May I ask why the `String` class isn't up for what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Probably, but why? You already have working code. A `ByteBuffer` isn't inherently circular by design.